# ZXing.Net PDF417 Barcode from HEX

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing

Is it possible to build a PDF417 barcode from a HEX? I tried something with ZXing, but it wont work with an encoded string in my case.

```
HEX: fe-30-09-33-31-37-30-31-30-32-30-31-f9-20-01-34-fe-30-01-20-fc-20-06
```

Other generators can do this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39471232/3236231), but now this solution costs a few thousand dollars. ZXing fits all my needs, but I cant find a propper way of using my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following code snippet should work as expected:

```
  [Test]
  public void Hex2Pdf417()
  {
     var hexStr = "fe3009333137303130323031f9200134fe300120fc2006";
     var byteArray = Enumerable.Range(0, hexStr.Length / 2).Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hexStr.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16)).ToArray();
     var byteArrayAsString = new String(byteArray.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray());

     // encode the string as PDF417
     var writer = new BarcodeWriter
     {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.PDF_417,
        Options = new PDF417EncodingOptions
        {
           Height = 200,
           Width = 200,
           Margin = 10
        }
     };
     var bitmap = writer.Write(byteArrayAsString);

     // try to decode the PDF417
     var reader = new BarcodeReader
     {
        Options = new DecodingOptions
        {
           PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>
           {
              BarcodeFormat.PDF_417
           },
           PureBarcode = true
        }
     };
     var result = reader.Decode(bitmap);

     // make sure, the result is the same as the original hex
     var resultBackToBytes = result.Text.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();
     var resultAsHexString = String.Join("", resultBackToBytes.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));

     Assert.That(resultAsHexString, Is.EqualTo(hexStr));
  }
```

Comment: Some HEX like "81" from CP850 throws the error:

Non-encodable character detected: (Unicode: 132)
Also when i decode the barcode here online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com, it shows that the saved HEX data isn't the original HEX. "FE" is saved as "5F".

Comment: Because of some small errors the code doesn't work correctly in all situations with the current version 0.14 of ZXing.Net.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working perfectly with the current version from the source code! Self compiled from https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/!